# use location dialog android

Tags: android, location, google-api-client, android-googleapiclient

I have to show Location Dialog on screen after login , i am try by folllowing code 
but getting this issue

I am calling this method in onCreate() , but showing error for the at  **PendingResult** Line.

> The type BroadcastReceiver.PendingResult is not generic; it cannot be
>   parameterized with arguments

And  also following error at this line **final Status status = result.getStatus();**

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Status to WifiConfiguration.Status

```
 public void locationDialog()
{
    if (googleApiClient == null) {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(LoginActivity.this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
            googleApiClient.connect();

            LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

            //**************************
            builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
            //**************************

            PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                    LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                    final Status status = result.getStatus();
                    final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                            // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                            // requests here.
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                            // a dialog.
                            try {
                                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                /*status.startResolutionForResult(
                                        getActivity(), 1000);*/
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                // Ignore the error.
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                            // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });            

    }

}
```

Comment: use this code for get latlong http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: @amitsharma i need to do this using Setting-api

Comment: You have imported the wrong `Status` class.

Comment: @1615903 i have change the status import  , i thing i am wrong at addConnectionCallbacks this line